# Making view shows only white page

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a simple view in a LARAVEL project.

It seems to work but it actually shows me only white page. Could anyone direct me on the right way to do this?

**route:**

```
Route::any('/privacy', 'SettingsController@settings');
```

**settingsController:**

```
class settingsController extends BaseController  
{

    public function settings()
    {
        return View::make("settings/privacy_settings");
    }
}
```

My `privacy_settings.blade.php` contain already some HTML and PHP content. But the page is totally empty

Comment: not sure but did you try defining the route without the slash (/) before the URI? i.e. Route::any('privacy', 'SettingsController@settings');

Comment: Your define routes controller and the controller class name are different. Your route should be Route::any('/privacy','settingsController@settings');

Comment: @sixFingersMan thats a great point, but didnt fix my problem anyway thank you for helping :)

Comment: Can you mention which laravel version are you using?

Comment: This happens to me as well if my log file is not writable by the web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),`  in your app.php file. You have probably and error somewhere but you haven't enabled the error reporting.
2. Which Laravel version are you using? `php artisan -V`

Next, add the error to the post above. Thanks.

Comment: laravel 4, debugging is set to true and no info in console or anywhere

Comment: Are you able in your settings method to return just a text? return 'test'; Is that visible on your screen?

Comment: returns the string "test"

Comment: Ok perfect next : Clear everything in your view and write <p>test</p> in it. Does it work? Oh and ofcourse return the view instead of the text message.

Comment: Oh hell! there was @stop at the end of the page.......... Thank you a lot man you are the best